# Script to get a GooglePhoto using filename stored in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-photos-api

I have a Googlesheets that has in one of its columns the filename (as "filename.jpg") of pictures stored in GooglePhotos (and/or Google Drive). I would like to have a script that would show me the selected picture when I click on a given cell of that particular column.

I'm quite familiar with Googlesheets Scripts and have looked at Google Photos API but don't know where to start.

Has anyone developed something like this and is willing to share? Any hints will be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution. You have to start from Browser API and this existing repo https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/tree/master/docs/dialog2sidebar

But before that you have to realize the next flow:

1. Get a string
2. Try to search the file with this string
3. Return the file or undefined